# Long running operation with timeout

Tags: c#, timeout

I have a long running operation that I need to wait for or timeout.
I have working code, but I would like your opinion on improving it.

```
public bool RegisterEquipmentListUpdate(int ID)
{
    if (Authentication.CheckSession(Session))
    {
        var wcfmonitoring = new WCFMonitoring.MonitoringDatabaseClient();
        try
        {
            bool timeout = false;
            DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
            //loop as long as the time isn't reached (600 seconds)
            while (!timeout)
            {
                if (wcfmonitoring.CheckForEquipmentUpdate(Authentication.GetSessionID(Session), Authentication.GetPTO(Session), ID))
                {
                    wcfmonitoring.Close();
                    //sleep before returning true, this is set so the importer can finish multiple files without the client refreshing on the first one
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    //sleep for 10 seconds before trying again
                    Thread.Sleep(10000);
                    //if the elapsed time is more than 10 minutes return false
                    if (start < DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-600))
                    {
                        wcfmonitoring.Close();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            wcfmonitoring.Abort();
        }
    }
    //return false in case of error
    return false;
}
```

Comment: have you considered async/await

Comment: Ok, good idea. I can return async Task<bool> and await Task.Delay(2000) and await Task.Delay(10000).

Comment: Yes which would be a lot cleaner than blocking thread

Comment: You could also consider changing the approach and using a timer as apposed to a busy wait....just thinking aloud here

Answer (score 1):

This is a rough draft, since I do not know the overall picture of your project. Some design might be improved to not even use this code (events, semaphores, mutexes, and other more predictable synchronization mechanisms). I rarely use this pattern for code that I control, more for code I cannot that I know is blocking. **This approach is risky, as it can lead to undesired state and data loss. You have been warned! (http://thedailywtf.com/articles/My-Tales) for reference!)**

If you stay on this path, I recommend A separate class/method be responsible for this sort of behaviour, to favour reuse, this also includes the possibility of having a CancellationToken passed in, just in case you change your mind about the request:

```
public async Task<T> WaitForActionCompletionOrTimeout<T>(Func<T> action, int timeout, CancellationToken? globalCancellation = null)
{
   var result = default(T); //return default for error

   var localCancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();
   var localAndGlobalCancellation = 
            CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(localCancellation.Token, 
                                                            globalCancellation.HasValue ? 
                                                            globalCancellation.Value : 
                                                            CancellationToken.None);

   Task cancelationTask = null;
   Task actionTask = null;

   try
   {
     cancelationTask = Task.Delay(timeout, localAndGlobalCancellation);
     actionTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
     {
       result = action.Invoke();
     }, localAndGlobalCancellation);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
     Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message);
     localCancellation.Cancel();
     return null;
   }

   await Task.WhenAny(actionTask, cancelationTask).ContinueWith(t => localCancellation.Cancel());
   return result;
}
```

Change the work method to return true or false, something like:

```
public bool CheckForUpdate()
 {
     using (var wcfmonitoring = new WCFMonitoring.MonitoringDatabaseClient())
     {
          var sw = new SpinWait();
          while (!wcfmonitoring.CheckForEquipmentUpdate(Authentication.GetSessionID(Session), Authentication.GetPTO(Session), ID)) //maybe  something shorter would work :) some variables are nice for debugging
          {
              sw.SpinOnce();  //magic Thread.Sleep(5) replacement with lots of goodies :) nice class to look at
          }

          Thread.Sleep(2000); //for the importer
          return true;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
var success = WaitForActionCompletionOrTimeout(() => CheckForUpdate, 600000 ); //I would so like 6.minutes.in.miliseconds.... ah dreams
```

This sort of approach (cancelling the worker)  could also be done with threads in a much shorter and brute-forcier way for a slow performance increase in case of very low timeouts.

I would also advise using **using** and if WcfMonitoring is not IDisposable, to make it IDisposable.

One more question: What is the intent/difference between calling Abort and Close in your code?